# Using sonarscanner to report dotnet code coverage - 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I'm using sonarscanner to get code coverage for a dotnet project.  However, the project coverage in SonarQube is reported as 0%.

I'm running the following commands to run tests, and capture the coverage.

```
dotnet test myproject/Tests/Project.Tests.Unit/Project.Tests.Unit.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover 
dotnet build-server shutdown 
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:key /d:sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="project/Tests/Project.Tests.Unit/coverage.opencover.xml" /n:key /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions=Test/** /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="**/Tests/**/coverage.opencover.xml" 
dotnet build project/Project.Service 
dotnet sonarscanner end
```

Adapted from https://medium.com/agilix/collecting-test-coverage-using-coverlet-and-sonarqube-for-a-net-core-project-ef4a507d4b28

As part of the output of `dotnet sonarscanner end` I see the following:

```
DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
```

Why am I not getting coverage reported in SonarQube?